# Scanf reads wrong value

Tags: c, input, scanf, newline, c89

I’m new to C programming language, I have wrote a simple code that reads two “char” values and prints them on the screen but the second one got empty value for a strange reason. What’s going wrong with my code?

```
Char c;
Scanf(“%c”,&c);
Printf(“Value:%c”,c);
Scanf(“%c”,&c);
Printf(“Value:%c”,c);
```

Output:
Value:g
Value:

Comment: What is `Char`,`Scanf`, and `Printf`?  C has similar functions/type (with a leading lowercase letter), but not those. Is that a typo or some local definition?  If the latter, you'll need to provide some detail.

Comment: There's nothing wrong.  You entered a 'g' and a newline, and the program printed 'Value:gValue:\n`

Answer (score 2):

(This is a comment, but comments are hard to format)

There's nothing wrong with your code (other than the failure to check the value returned by scanf and deal with errors or incorrect input).  Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void)
{
        char c;
        scanf("%c",&c);
        printf("Value:%c",c);
        scanf("%c",&c);
        printf("Value:%c",c);
        return 0;
}
$ gcc a.c
$ printf 'abc' | ./a.out
Value:aValue:b
```

Perhaps what's "wrong" is that you have newlines in your input.  (eg, you are entering data interactively and forgetting that when you hit "return" a newline is inserted into the input stream.)

Comment: *Obviously* there were newlines in the input.  No need to tease the OP with a coy answer like this.

Comment: I disagree that it's obvious, and this is not at all intended to "tease" the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal was to read two "interesting" characters, and if you don't think that whitespace characters like space and newline are "interesting", you've been tripped up by number six out of the seventeen things about `scanf` that are designed to trip up the unwary: `%c` *does* read whitespace characters.

If you want `scanf` to skip over whitespace characters, so that `%c` will read the next, non-whitespace or "interesting" character, simply include a space character in the format string before the `%c`:

```
char c;
scanf(" %c", &c);
printf("Value: %c\n",c);
scanf(" %c", &c);
printf("Value: %c\n",c);
```

In a `scanf` format string, the presence of a whitespace character indicates that you want `scanf` to skip over *all* whitespace at that point in the input.

Normally you don't have to worry about skipping whitespace with `scanf`, because most of the other format specifiers -- `%d`, `%f`, `%s`, etc. -- automatically skip over any whitespace, if necessary, before they start parsing their input.  But `%c` is special: someone thought you might want to use it to read whitespace characters, so it doesn't skip them, so if you don't want to read them, you have to skip them yourself, with that space character in the format string first.

Comment: Hi, why the new line is considered an input even though the user have to press enter to let scanf function get value? (Like the case with C# and most other programming languages out there)

Comment: @Jobert001 The `scanf` function works on an uninterrupted *stream* of characters.  Now, it's true, input from the keyboard is normally broken up into lines, and your program doesn't see anything until you hit the Return key to indicate you're done typing (at which point all the characters on the line become available to your program all at once), but that's lower-level functionality, that has nothing to do with `scanf`.

Comment: I invite you to run this code: `while(scanf("%c", &c) == 1) printf("You typed: %c\n");`.  Or this similar code: `int c; while((c = getchar()) != EOF) printf("You typed: %c\n");`.  Notice that when you type some characters, and hit Return, the "you typed" lines come out all at once.  Think about this carefully.  (See also [these class notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx6b.html).)

Comment: @Jobert001 So, again, `scanf` just sees a stream of characters, and it treats all whitespace characters -- spaces, tabs, newlines, etc -- the same.  Why was it designed this way?  I can't tell you.  (I wasn't there, it was before my time.)  I do agree that it's not always convenient that it works that way.  In fact, I advise all C programmers to learn other ways of doing user input, not involving `scanf`, and to abandon `scanf` entirely as soon as they can.  It's really not a very good tool.